# Saving drawing on Tradingview widget?

Tags: javascript, html, tradingview-api

Currently we are using TradingView Widget to display charts ( we would love to use the SDK but we don't have our own data ) and we are wondering if we could somehow save the drawings and annotations from the chart so when a user leaves the website and come back he can look at the same drawings and annotations he has done before?

I wouldn't mind storing the annotations and drawing data on my website but I don't know where to find this option?

Comment: Not possible with the widget, only the full Charting Library.  You can use external API's (like from an exchange) to get data to your charts by the way.

Comment: @NickFriskel thanks for the input. We're now migrating to full chart SDK.
Hopefully, we will find out how to save the indicators properly on our side and store it on our website, thank you.